# could parent object be created using super to call parent method

Tags: java, super

Would the parent object be created , if we use the super keyword to call the method of the parent class in child object?

Outcomes show that both Mybase and MySub have the same reference address. Not sure whether it is a good demo.

class Mybase {

```
public void address() {
    System.out.println("super:" + this);
    System.out.println( this.getClass().getName());
}
```

}

class MySub extends Mybase {

```
public void address() {
    System.out.println("this:" + this);
    System.out.println( this.getClass().getName());
}

public void info() {
    System.out.println("this:" + this);
    super.address();
}
```

}

public class SuperTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MySub().info();
}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you try and find out?

Comment: it creates instance of child class but it needs to initialize members of parent class

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions like this are very vague and likely to attract downvotes. Try to make a small piece of code illustrating your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's find out!

Your test isn't *quite* going to answer your question. If you want to see if an object is created, why not create a constructor that prints to the console when called?

```
public class Test {

    static class Parent {
        Parent() {
            System.out.println("Parent constructor called");
        }

        void method() {
            System.out.println("Parent method called");
        }
    }

    static class Child extends Parent {
        Child() {
            System.out.println("Child constructor called");
        }

        @Override
        void method() {
            System.out.println("Child method called");
            super.method();
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new Child().method();
    }
}
```

If you run this, you get this output:

```
Parent constructor called
Child constructor called
Child method called
Parent method called
```

So as you can see, when `method()` was called, no `Parent` object was created when the `super` keyword was used. So the answer to your question is "no".

---

The reason is because `super` and `super()` are *different*. `super` (no parentheses) is used to access members of the parent class. `super()` (with parentheses) is a call to the parent constructor, and is only valid *inside a constructor* as the *first* call in the constructor. So using `super` (no parentheses) will *not* create a new object.

Also, `super()` doesn't actually create a new, independent `Parent` object. It just does the initialization work for the fields of `Parent` that is needed before the child constructor continues.